# Juego de ahorcado en java con interfaz grafica no cambia imagenes y si adivinas la primera letra sale un null en vez de la letra

Tags: java, java-swing

Exactamente lo que dice el titulo.

**Funcionamiento deseado:**

Es un juego de ahorcado con imagenes. pones la letra en un textfield y arriba hay un campo con guiones. luego das click en verificar, si esta bien los guiones que corresponden a esa letra seran cambiados por la letra de lo contrario la imagen se cambia a la correspondiente que muestra al monito con una extremidad mas. y asi hasta que se cuelgue el mono. Si se gana se muestra mensaje de que se ha ganado, de lo contrario se muestra mensaje de que se ha perdido. Para reiniciar el juego se hace click en nueva palabra y ya esta.

**Funcionamiento actual:**

Las imagenes del hombre de palo no se cambian cuando me equivoco y ademas si adivinas la primera letra de una palabra el campo de los guiones muestra lo siguiente:

palabra : carro
null  y luego los guiones de las letras sin adivinar

en vez de:
c  y luego los guiones de las letras sin adivinar

---

**Variables:**

- pic y pzet: variables de imagenes
- zzslow: textfield para poner la letra y otro para mostrar los guiones de la palabra y sustituir por letras adivinadas.
- bnew: boton de palabra nueva
- blook: boton para verificar si la letra se encuentra en la palabra a adivinar
- bexit: boton para salir

---

CODIGO

```java
package ahorcas;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Ahorcas extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
        {
    private JTextField zzslow1,zzslow2;
    private JButton blook,bexit,bnew;
    private JLabel lb1,lb2,lb4,pic,pic1,pic2,pic3,pic4,pic5,pic6;
    private String word;
    private String []limes = new String [10];
    public int  tencount =0, fireball=0, ayo=0;
    private JLabel pzet,pzet1,pzet2,pzet3,pzet4,pzet5,pzet6;

    public Ahorcas()
    {

        super ("Hangman ");
        lb1 = new JLabel (" Word : ");
        lb1.setBounds(200,90,100,20);
        lb2 = new JLabel (" Letter : ");
        lb2.setBounds(200,90,100,20);
        lb4 = new JLabel (" ");
        lb4.setBounds(140,40,200,20);

         zzslow1 = new JTextField (" ");
         zzslow1.setEditable(false);
         zzslow1.setBounds(170,20,200,20);
         zzslow2 = new JTextField (" ");
         zzslow2.setBounds(250,90,80,20);

        blook = new JButton("Verify");
        blook.setBounds(200,120,100,20);

        bexit = new JButton("Exit");
        bexit.setBounds(200,200,100,20);

        bnew = new JButton("New Word ");
        bnew.setBounds(200,160,100,20);

        bexit.addActionListener(this);
        blook.addActionListener(this);
        bnew.addActionListener(this);

        Icon picdesk = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\nada.jpg");
        pic = new JLabel (picdesk);
        pic.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

          Icon pzet1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im1.jpg");
        pic1 = new JLabel (pzet1);
        pic1.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

         Icon pzet2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im2.jpg");
        pic2 = new JLabel (pzet2);
        pic2.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

           Icon pzet3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im3.jpg");
        pic3 = new JLabel (pzet3);
        pic3.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

           Icon pzet4 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im4.jpg");
        pic4 = new JLabel (pzet4);
        pic4.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

         Icon pzet5 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im5.jpg");
        pic5 = new JLabel (pzet5);
        pic5.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

         Icon pzet6 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Tania\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Ahorcas\\src\\ahorcas\\im6.jpg");
        pic6 = new JLabel (pzet6);
        pic6.setBounds(30,110,160,170);

        pictures();
        newword();

        getContentPane().add(lb1);
        getContentPane().add(lb2);
        getContentPane().add(lb4);
        getContentPane().add(zzslow1);
        getContentPane().add(zzslow2);
        getContentPane().add(blook);
        getContentPane().add(bexit);
        getContentPane().add(bnew);

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            setSize(400,500);
            setVisible(true);

    } 

    private void newword()
    {
       String[][]high= { 
                         {"cow","shark","zebra","cat","fish","snake","spider","lion"},
                         {"leo","scorpio","taurus","pisces","aquarius","gemini","capricorn"},       
                         {"italy","france","mexico","china","taiwan","japan","india"},
                         {"mango", "strawberry","banana","apple","cherry","pear","lime"},
                       };

       int joker = (int)(Math.random()*3);
       int akira = (int)(Math.random()*3);
           word = high[joker][akira];
         if (joker == 0)
         {
           lb4.setText("Animals");
         }
           if (joker == 1)
         {
           lb4.setText("Zodiac Signs");
         }

             if (joker == 2)
         {
           lb4.setText("Countries");
         }
             if (joker == 3)
         {
           lb4.setText("Fruits");
         }
             for (int j=0; j<word.length();j++)
             {

                 tencount++;
                 limes[j] = "_";
                 zzslow1.setText(zzslow1.getText()+limes[j]+ " ");

             }
        }


       private void pictures ()
       {

          if (ayo==0)
             {
                 pic.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==1)
             {
                 pic1.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==2)
             {
                 pic2.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==3)
             {
                 pic3.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==4)
             {
                 pic4.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==5)
             {
                 pic5.setVisible(true);
             }
         if (ayo==6)
             {
                 pic6.setVisible(true);
             }

           // KKKKKKKKKKKKKK
         if (ayo==0)
             {
                 getContentPane().add(pic);
             }
         if (ayo==1)
             {
                 getContentPane().add(pic1);
             }
         if (ayo==2)
             {
                  getContentPane().add(pic2);
             }
         if (ayo==3)
             {
                  getContentPane().add(pic3);
             }
         if (ayo==4)
             {
                  getContentPane().add(pic4);
             }
         if (ayo==5)
             {
                  getContentPane().add(pic5);
             }
         if (ayo==6)
             {
                  getContentPane().add(pic6);
             }
       }


       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getSource().equals(bexit))
            { System.exit(0);}

             if (e.getSource().equals(blook))
             {
                 char letter =carat(zzslow2.getText());
                 String letter2 = zzslow2.getText();
                 String atem = zzslow1.getText();
                 ayo++;

                 for (int i=0; i< word.length();i++)
                 {
                     if (letter== word.charAt(i))
                     {
                         limes[i]=letter2;
                         fireball++;
                         zzslow1.setText("null");
                         ayo=ayo-1;

                         for (int j=0;j< word.length();j++)
                         {
                             zzslow1.setText(zzslow1.getText()+limes[j]+ " ");
                         }
                     }


                 }


             }


        pictures();
        if (fireball == tencount)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have won !!!");
                zzslow2.setEditable(false);
            }
        if (ayo == 6)
             {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have won !!!");
                zzslow2.setEditable(false);
            }
           zzslow2.setText(null);
        if (e.getSource().equals(bnew))
          {
              zzslow1.setText(null);
              tencount=0;
              newword ();
              ayo=0;
              fireball=0;
              zzslow2.setEditable(true);

              pic.setVisible(true);
              pic1.setVisible(true);
              pic2.setVisible(true);
              pic3.setVisible(true);
              pic4.setVisible(true);
              pic5.setVisible(true);
              pic6.setVisible(true);

          }
        }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Ahorcas y = new Ahorcas();

    }

   private char carat (String txt)
   {
       return txt.charAt(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Un consejo: usa un array para guardar las JLabels `pic`, `pic1`... `pic6`: el método pictures te quedaría algo como `pics[ayo].setVisible(true); getContentPane().add(pics[ayo])`.